# How to add shortcut to Cinnamon taskbar

Tags: ubuntu, cinnamon

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Cinnamon desktop. After trying to create a shortcut for a PDF file to Cinnamon's Taskbar, I found maybe I should have searched for a folder containing the Taskbar's configuration information and create a launcher there. And by the way I don't know if I've guessed right or if yes, where would it be! How would I add the shortcut to the pdf file and then place it in the Taskbar?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A simple GUI method:

Right-click *Menu* and then click *Configure*.

[image: Cinnamon Menu]

Click *Open the Menu Editor*.

Optionally create a new folder for your custom links. Create a new item that opens the file, using the command, `evince /path/to/file.pdf`, or whichever PDF viewer you want to use.

[image: Cinnamon Menu Item]

Close the menu editor and right-click on your new menu item, selecting *Add to Panel*.

[image: Cinnamon Menu]

If you chose to make a new folder in the menu, it exists in `~/.local/share/desktop-directories/` as a file with the extension, `.directory`. If you chose to make a new menu item, it exists in `~/.local/share/applications/` as a file with the extension, `.desktop`. These were created by `alacarte`. They are regular text files; and, now that you know their location, you could do this manually, too.

The rest of the files for the menu are located in `/usr/share/desktop-directories` and `/usr/share/applications`.

Comment: Thanks for the great solution and the supporting screenshots

Answer (score 11):

There is another way to do this besides Christopher's method.  I've tested it in Linux Mint 17.3.

Simply find the application in the Menu and drag and drop into the launcher.  I struggled with the whole "adding shortcut" thing, until I thought to try that.  As a bonus, it brings the app icon along as well.

Comment: This works well though the first answer is the one to use when you've downloaded and installed new software that isn't an application in the Menu. Note: you can use just about any reasonable image as the icon though your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

1). In “Menu”, navigate to the programme which will be used to open the desired file.
2). Right-click the programme shortcut in “Menu”, and select “Add to panel”
3). On the Panel, right-click the newly added item, then click “Edit”.
3). Re-name it to the desired file, then note the initial text in the “Command” box, e.g. “libreoffice --calc %U” which is the command Linux uses to open the programme. This must be modified to add the path to the desired file. Copy this command to the clipboard, then select “Browse” in the Launcher Properties box, and navigate to the file you wish the panel shortcut to open. Select it, and it will appear in the “Command” box in the Launcher properties box. Click the mouse button immediately to the left of the newly inserted link, and paste the previously saved link in this position, so that we now read, for example, “libreoffice --calc %U/“link to file”.
4). Select “OK”, the Launcher Properties box will close, and the new Panel launcher will be available.